# Using FQL to return friend's data

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to use FQL to return a user's friends that meet certain requirements, i.e. return friends that are majoring in Computer Science, etc? Here's the current FQL query I am using to return friend data, how could these be modified to accomplish this and if not, what would be alternate solutions?

```
 try{
        $fql    =   "select name,education,work from user WHERE uid IN (select uid2 from friend where uid1=($user))";
        $param  =   array(
            'method'    => 'fql.query',
            'query'     => $fql,
            'callback'  => ''
        );
        $fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);
    }
    catch(Exception $o){
        d($o);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is work or not but try to add your fql query to something like this,

```
select name,education,work from user WHERE uid IN (select uid2 from friend where uid1=($user) AND education.type = "Computer Science"
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The user table is just one huge table and the field is education which is an array of data. Can the data in that array be individually accessed via FQL? This is the description of the education array from the documentation: education array 
A list of the user's education history. Contains year and type fields, and school object (name, id, type, and optional year, degree, concentration array, classes array, and with array ).

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Though it is very late for answering question, it will help somebody. That's why answering this question.

We have to parse resultset given by facebook. Facebook doesn't allow us to check that.

```
$freinds_list=$facebook->api(array('method'=>'fql.query',
                    'query'=>"SELECT uid, name, education_history
                       FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = $user) ORDER BY name"));

            $i=0;

            foreach($freinds_list as $friend) {
                $j=0;
                $connection=0;
                foreach($friend['education_history'] as $education) {
                    if(strstr($education['type'],'Computer Science')) {
                        $user[$i]=$friend['name'];
                        $i++;                        
                    }
                    $j++;
                }
            }
```